# Find My shows that my iMac is still logged in to previous owner

Tags: imac, find-my

I recently purchased an iMac 2020 which had been previously brought via Amazon in September and returned for whatever reason. It still has its warranty until August 2023 and basically new condition. I can use the iMac with no problems and log into my own iCloud however the find my iMac is logged in by the previous owner.

It has their email and obviously I cannot login with the password to disable it. I’ve tried to email them via this email to ask them to remove it from their devices but I’ve had no response.

My question is, do they have to power to somehow erase eveything off the iMac? Should I be worried?

Could I use the warranty I have left on this to someone get a new one to avoid this situation all together?

Comment: I have purchased from Aoples returned section several times - never an issue.

Comment: jmast - you'll never know unless the guy replies whether he did report it or whether he's just abandoned Apple or that email address. He could have just walked away - leaving emails to pile up in to him an 'old account' that he never checks. Maybe he never looks at Find My ever again. He neither knows nor cares about the old Mac. However, if you ever have to go through recovery, or sometimes even for updates… something, sometime is going to need **his** Apple ID & p/w to authorise it… & you are then completely stuck, permanently. As far as the Mac is concerned **you do not own it**.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the responses. I was worried about going through all this hassle of what you suggested. The person who’s email was logged into find my Mac responded to my numerous emails. Turned out they all went to their junk mail which is why they didn’t reply straight away. 

They apologised and removed themselves from find my mac which has just resolved what seemed to be a major headache for me. Who says Christmas isn’t the time for miracles? Merry Christmas everyone!

Answer (score 6):

You have a dilemma.
The person who sold it should have ensured that the previous owner had already released it from Find My.

That they didn't leaves two possibilities.
They forgot to check.
It was stolen.

You could contact the previous owner and ask them to release it from Find My.
They might.
They might not.
They might be happy to find their stolen goods & want it back.

Apple will release it for you with proof of *ownership*. This is not the same as proof of purchase. You only have proof of purchase. The person with it locked to Find My has a better claim.

I think, as you bought it from Amazon, your safest bet is to send it back to Amazon & get your money back.
This is not necessarily 'fair' but it absolves you of responsibility in dealing with a potentially stolen Mac - whether stolen or not you are still held at ransom by the person it is still locked to. They can erase it at any time.
Amazon will just give you your money back, if the seller gets awkward.